# How do I do this one?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

can you help me out with this one ?

if $F(2)=3, F′(2)=4, F(3)=2, F′(3)=5$  and $G(2)=3, G′(2)=6, G(3)=6, G′(3)=6,$

what is $H′(2)$ if $H(x)=G(F(x))$ ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to take the derivative of $H(x)$. So using chain rule you get $H'(x) = G'(F(x))F'(x)$. So now we have that $H'(2) = G'(F(2))F'(2)$. Which can be simplified to $H'(2) = 4 \cdot G'(3) =4\cdot 6 = 24.$

Comment: much appreciated :D